# ElasticSearch returned nested property not mapping to C# class

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a nested object in ElasticSearch that I am trying to map into a List in C# but it is always returning a `NULL`

My C# class looks like this:

```
    [ElasticsearchType(RelationName = "part")]
    public class Product 
    {
         [JsonPropertyName("PartNumber")]
         [Keyword(Name = "PartNumber")]
         public string ProductNumber { get; set; }

         [JsonPropertyName("Pricing")]
         [Nested]
         public IList<PartPricing> Pricing { get; set; }
    }

    [ElasticsearchType(RelationName = "Pricing")]
    public class PartPricing
    {
        [Keyword(Name = "Application")]
        public string Application { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("BasePrice")]
        [Number(NumberType.Double, Name = "BasePrice")]
        public decimal BasePrice { get; set; }

        [Boolean(Name = "IsFreeShipping")]
        public bool IsFreeShipping { get;set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("CustomerPrice")]
        [Number(NumberType.Double, Name = "CustomerPrice")]
        public decimal CustomerPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

When I build out my query using NEST C# then run the following

`var response = _context.Client.Search<T>(searchDescriptor);`

If I Look at the response the DEBUG information the REQUEST looks like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "PartNumber": {
                            "value": "1001"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "_source": {
        "includes": [
            "id",
            "PartNumber",
            "Pricing"
        ]
    }
}
```

And the response looks like this:

```
{
    "took": 63,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 6,
        "successful": 6,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "parts",
                "_type": "part",
                "_id": "~111111",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 1234
                    "PartNumber": "1001",
                    "Pricing": [
                        {
                            "BasePrice": 95.0,
                            "IsFreeShipping": true,
                            "Application": "TEST",
                            "CustomerPrice": 161.5
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "sort": [
                    2,
                    470
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So I can see that the pricing information is being returned from the query but it is not being correctly mapped into my C# class as the Pricing property is always `NULL`. I'm guessing there is something incorrect with my Class definitions but I am not sure what. This is my first time working with ElasticSearch. I can return other decimal or string values without issue but the Nested values are not returning at all.

Comment: I was able to eventually figure out the issue. I guess when using a NESTED property it is required to add a name attribute as well so in my Product class I needed to make the property as follows [Nested(Name = "Pricing")]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to eventually figure out the issue. I guess when using a NESTED property it is required to add a name attribute as well so in my Product class I needed to make the property as follows

`[Nested(Name = "Pricing")]`

Comment: the only way I got it to work was to just add [Nested]